# Quando devemos usar trás e traz?

Tags: ortografia

Em que momentos devemos usar a palavras trás e traz, estas palavras parecem tão parecidas, mas possuem diferença?

Comment: E tráz? :D piadoca, hein?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Trás ou traz

Estas duas palavras existem na língua portuguesa e estão corretas. Porém, os seus significados são diferentes e devem ser usadas em situações diferentes. A palavra trás é um advérbio de lugar, indicando uma situação posterior, ou seja, atrás, após. Traz é a forma conjugada do verbo trazer na 3ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo ou na 2ª pessoa do singular do imperativo. Trazer significa levar, transportar para perto de quem fala.

O advérbio de lugar trás tem sua origem na palavra em latim trans. Vem sempre acompanhado de uma preposição, normalmente de ou para, formando assim uma locução adverbial. É também uma palavra comumente utilizada na locução prepositiva por trás de.

**Exemplos:**

- As crianças devem viajar no banco de trás.
- Quando ele a chamou, ela olhou para trás.
- As cartolinas estão guardadas por trás do armário.

O verbo trazer tem sua origem na palavra em latim trahere e é um verbo irregular, ou seja, não se encaixa nos modelos fixos de conjugação verbal, possuindo alterações nos radicais e nas terminações quando conjugado. É muito utilizado pelos falantes, possuindo diversos significados. Refere-se principalmente ao ato de transportar ou encaminhar para este lugar, mas também pode ser sinônimo de oferecer, vestir, ocasionar, atrair, conter em si, apresentar, sugerir, herdar, manter, citar, entre outros. Traz é a forma conjugada do verbo trazer na 3ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo ou na 2ª pessoa do singular do imperativo.

**Verbo trazer - Presente do indicativo:**

- (Eu) trago
- (Tu) trazes
- (Ele) traz
- (Nós) trazemos
- (Vós) trazeis
- (Eles) trazem

**Verbo trazer - Imperativo:**
 - (Eu) ---
 - (Tu) traz
 - (Ele) traga
 - (Nós) tragamos
 - (Vós) trazei
 - (Eles) tragam

**Exemplos:**

- Traz essa caixa! (2ª pessoa do singular do imperativo)
- Não se preocupem, ele traz o material. (3ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo)

As palavras trás e traz apresentam a mesma fonética, ou seja, são pronunciadas de forma igual, mas os seus significados e escritas são diferentes. A este tipo de palavras chamamos palavras homófonas. Na língua portuguesa, existem diversas palavras homófonas: trás/traz, acento/assento, conserto/concerto, cela/sela, sinto/cinto, cozer/coser,…

Comment: _trás_ também é uma preposição e uma interjeição. **Trás!**